# Let variable undefined in shared example rspec

Tags: rspec

I have this code

```
describe ChocolateTotalsCalculator do

  shared_examples "a fully redeemed set of chocolates" do
    it "returns a final set of chocolates: #{final_chocolates}" do
      expect(subject).to eq(final_chocolates)
    end
  end

  describe "#calculate" do
    subject { chocolate_calculator.calculate }

    context "wrappers are redeemed zero times" do
      context "row is [cash: 0, price: 0, wrappers: 0, type: 'dark']" do

        it_behaves_like "a fully redeemed set of chocolates" do
          let(:row) { CSV::Row.new(csv_headers,[0,0,0,"dark"]) }
          let(:final_chocolates) {
            {
              "milk" => 0,
              "dark" => 0,
              "white" => 0,
              "sugar free" => 0
            }
          }
        end
      end
```

but I get this error:

```
NameError:
  undefined local variable or method `final_chocolates' for #<Class:0x00007f9322b6c148>
```

What is happening? Why can't I use a shared example in this way?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line

```
it "returns a final set of chocolates: #{final_chocolates}" do
```

`final_chocolates` is only available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) and not available on an example group.